# How to change the size of dots in a mpl-scatter-density plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, scatter-plot

I am using [mpl-scatter-density](https://github.com/astrofrog/mpl-scatter-density) to make a density plot in python.
However, the dots are extremely small.

What should I do in order to make the scatter dots bigger?

I used this code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mpl_scatter_density

n = 5_000
x = np.random.normal(4, 2, n)
y = np.random.normal(3, 1, n)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection='scatter_density')
density = ax.scatter_density(x, y)
fig.colorbar(density, label='Number of points per pixel')
```

And the output is:

[image]

Comment: I'm not very familiar with `mpl_scatter_density`, but it seems you are just supposed to set a lower DPI like `dpi=20`: https://github.com/astrofrog/mpl-scatter-density/issues/34